# User is undefined when trying to get server owner. Discord.js v13

Tags: discord, discord.js

I have been trying to make a serverinfo command since yesterday but i keep getting an error with the code. I am using discord.js v13. Here is my code. In the stats field for the owner it says user is undefined. For someone else it works but for me I keep getting an error.

```js
const { Message, Client, MessageEmbed, MessageAttachment } = require("discord.js");
const moment = require('moment');

const verificationLevels = {
    NONE: "None",
    LOW: "Low",
    MEDUIM: "Medium",
    HIGH: "High",
    VERY_HIGH: "Very High"
}

const regions = {
    brazil: 'Brazil',
    europe: 'Europe',
    hongkong: 'Hong Kong',
    india: 'India',
    japan: 'Japan',
    russia: 'Russia',
    singapore: 'Singapore',
    southafrica: 'South Africa',
    sydney: 'Sydney',
    'us-central': 'US Central',
    'us-east': 'US East',
    'us-west': 'US West',
    'us-south': 'US South'
}

module.exports = {
    name: "serverinfo",
    /**
     *
     * @param {Client} client
     * @param {Message} message
     * @param {String[]} args
     */
    run: async (client, message, args) => {
        const roles = message.guild.roles.cache.sort((a, b) => b.position - a.position).map(role => role.toString()).slice(0, -1)
        
        const members = message.guild.members.cache;
        
        const channels = message.guild.channels.cache;
        
        const emojis = message.guild.emojis.cache
        
        let rolesdisplay;
        
        if(roles.length < 20){
            rolesdisplay = roles.join(' ')
        } else {
            rolesdisplay = roles.slice(20).join(' ')
        }
        
        const { guild } = message
        
        const { name, region, memberCoutn, owner } = guild
        
        const icon = guild.iconURL()
        
        var serverEmbed = new MessageEmbed()
        .setColor("RANDOM")
        .setTitle(`All Server Information for ${name}`)
        .setThumbnail(message.guild.iconURL())
        .addField('General Information', [
            `**Name:** ${name}`,
            `**ID:** ${message.guild.id}`,
            `**Owner:** ${message.guild.owner.user.tag}`,
            `**Region:** ${regions[message.guild.region]}`,
            `**Boost Tier:** ${message.guild.premuimTier ? `Tier ${message.guild.premuimTier}`: 'None'}`,
            `**Verification Level:** ${verificationLevels[message.guild.verificationLevel]}`,
            `**Boost Level:** ${message.guild.premuimSubscriptionCount || '0'}`,
            `**Created At:** ${moment(message.guild.createdTimestamp).format('LT')} ${moment(message.guild.createdTimestamp).format('LL')} ${moment(message.guild.createdTimestamp).fromNow()}`,
            '\u200b'
        ])
        
        .addField('Stats', [
            `**Role Count:** ${roles.length}`,
            `**Emoji Count:** ${emojis.size}`,
            `**Normal Emoji Count:** ${emojis.filter(emoji => !emoji.animated).size}`,
            `**Animated Emoji Count:** ${emojis.filter(emoji => emoji.animated).size}`,
            `**Member Count:** ${message.guild.memberCount}`,
            `**Humans:** ${members.filter(member => !member.user.bot).size}`,
            `**Bots:** ${members.filter(member => member.user.bit).size}`,
            `**Online:** ${members.filter(member => member.presence.status === 'online').size}`,
            `**Offline:** ${members.filter(member => member.presence.status === 'offline').size}`,
            `**Do Not Disturb:** ${members.filter(member => member.presence.status === 'dnd').size}`,
            `**Idle:** ${members.filter(member => member.presence.status === 'idle').size}`,
            `**Text Channels:** ${channels.filter(channel => channel.type === 'text').size}`,
            `**Voice Channels:** ${channels.filter(channel => channel.type === 'voice').size}`,
            '\u200b'
        ])
        
        .addField(`Roles [${roles.length - 1}]`, rolesdisplay)
        
        message.channel.send({ embeds: [serverEmbed]})
    },
};
```

And here is my error

```js
(node:24) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'user' of undefined
    at Object.run (/home/container/commands/Utility/serverinfo.js:66:47)
    at Client.<anonymous> (/home/container/axo.js:60:19)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:24) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 2)
(node:24) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

If anyone knows the answer please tell. Is there anything I am missing to define?

Answer (score 3):

There is no property `Guild.owner` in discord.js v13.

You could use [`Guild.ownerId`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/master/class/Guild?scrollTo=ownerId).

```js
const owner = members.find(member => member.id === message.guild.ownerId);
```

Or [`Guild.fetchOwner()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/master/class/Guild?scrollTo=fetchOwner).

```js
const owner = await message.guild.fetchOwner();
```

Comment: How do i get the Owner id?

Comment: i did but it returns as undifined when i do

```
const owner = await message.guild.fetchOwner();

console.log(owner.id);
```

Comment: Why don't you use `message.guild.ownerId` directly?

Answer (score 0):

The guildObject in V13 doesn't have an owner property anymore, use the fetchOwner() method instead, more info here: https://discordjs.guide/additional-info/changes-in-v13.html#guild-owner